# Vue webpack project presents blank page after building

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In dev mode everything works fine but after building with static it's just blank page! I've seen a lot of issues but no one is similar to mine.

router/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Main from '@/components/Main'
import BrandPage from '@/components/BrandPage'
import Article from '@/components/Article'

Vue.use(Router)

console.log("Router");

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Main,
      props: dynamicPropsMain
    }

    ...

  ]
})
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
console.log("main");

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted() {
    console.log("App");
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Also I'm logging every component this way:

```
mounted() {
  console.log("Main");
}
```

And this is what I see in console when I open the index.html file from dist folder:
[image: Browser console]

There's no an error btw!

I changed all paths to relative in index.html as you can see:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>cosmetic</title>
  <link href=./static/css/app.6e402e4fa684582f062c00087423d24c.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body>
  <script src=https://use.fontawesome.com/5c25b8d8cc.js></script>
  <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js></script>
  <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
  <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js></script>
  <div id=app></div>
  <script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/vendor.5f799c4e5a271a20f280.js></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/app.3990053e5416194b5d89.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

These all make me to think that the problem with router and I don't know how to check deeper...

Please anyone help me with that!!! I'll be very grateful!

Comment: I can see a variable called ``dynamicPropsMain`` in your router definition, which isn't defined, nor imported.
Can you verify the variable exists in the context and isn't preventing the router to match the ``/`` route?

Comment: how exactly do you "open" index.html? Maybe try using a webserver for this. E.g. for VS Code use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Comment: @Farsad it exists. I didn't attach it because it's kinda extra info not relating to the problem. Please pay attention that dev mode works normally :)

Comment: @MartinTuróci it should work anyway... I changed the paths to .js and .css
Thank you though !! I'll try it and write about result

Comment: @serejaonly Thanks for confirming, but it might be it, just have an eye on required query params as they can prevent the route from getting matched in runtime. Anyway, I suggest you try debugging your application using Vue devtools plugin.

Comment: @Farsad if there's a problem with some variable or parameter I could see the error in console... I guess even in dev mode. Am I wrong?(
thank you a lot! Does this plugin work with static?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to open the index.html? This will not work.
In order to use your Vue application, you have to serve the entire dist folder over a Web server.

Comment: why is it so important? I guess it would be so if you have absolute paths in index.html (for serving) because I have a lot of examples where it works fine